# Call to DBContext throws exception (code first, create DB)

Tags: entity-framework-5

I wanted to try EF5 as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542

But as soon as

using (var db = new BloggingContext())

is reached an System.InvalidOperationException is thrown with additional details saying that "The type 'ConsoleApplication1.Program+Blog' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject."

No database is created. I'm using VS 2012 Express for Windows Desktop and SQL Server 2012. The database explorer can connect to the local SQLExpress instance without problems.

Any ideas?

Cheers, mttmjapj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, found the culprit. I unconsciously put the source for Blog and Post into the program class. Which obviously is nested and therefore can't work.